# use function to provide values for spring spel

Tags: spring, spring-el

I am using spring evaluation language as follow:

```
Map<String, Object> bigMap = loader.loadBigMap();
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariables(bigMap);
```

my issue is that most of the data contained in the bigMap is not used.
Instead I would prefer to lazy load only what I need by passing a function to the evaluation context, something like:

```
Function<String, Object> lazyloader = name -> loader.loadForName(name);
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariables(lazyloader);
```

but I could not find how to do this. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a lambda - SpEL functions must be static methods.

```
public void registerFunction(String name, Method method)
```

```java
public class MyUtils {

    public static Object lazyLoader(String key) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Use `Class.getDeclaredMethod(...)` to get a reference to the method.